# java script is not working in content page

Tags: javascript, html, content-pages

By clicking image "imgAdd", I want to set visibility of div "divAddCustomerInfo" to true by using JavaScript. But click on image isn't working. I think that is because JavaScript isn't working. Anyone can help? Yhanks in advance.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function imgAdd_click() {
        document.getElementById("divAddCustomerInfo").style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
</script>
<div id="divCustomerBody" style="margin-left:300px; margin-top:50px;">
    <h1>Customer</h1>
    <hr style="color:gray; width:900px; margin-left: 0px;" />
    <br />
    <div id="divOperationSymbol" style="height:100px; width:900px; ">

        <div id="divAddition" onclick="divAddition_click()" style="height:100px; float:left; width:300px; " >
            <img id="imgAdd" onclick="imgAdd_click()" src="001446-3d-transparent-glass-icon-media-a-media35-add.png" style="height:70px; width:70px; display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" />
            <label id="lblAdd" onclick="lblADD_click()" style="color: #a6a6a6; margin-left:100px;">Add Customer</label>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
    <div id="divAddCustomerInfo" style="visibility: hidden; margin-left:300px; margin-top:50px;">

</div>
```

Comment: Add parentheses `()` to your `onclick`. It should be like this `onclick=imgAdd_click()`

Comment: sorry, still not working

Comment: You try my answer let me know..

Comment: @waqarahmedsomra `visible="false"` isn't a valid html attribute. Change it to `style="visibility:hidden"`

Comment: @PrateekGupta changed. still no success

Comment: @waqarahmedsomra Check in browser developer tools, whether that element is rendered at server or not.

Comment: @PrateekGupta div "divAddCustomerInfo" is no more runat server. i have changed it. its now a just a html div

Comment: Your question and examples are not clear. What "isn't working" exactly? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This question seems to of turned into a guessing game

Comment: Thanku everyone. its solved. in div "divAddCustomerInfo" i have a table and it was set to visible. my mistake. m so sorry. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

**Change the following**

```
<div id="divAddCustomerInfo" runat="server" visible="false" style="margin-left:300px; margin-top:50px;">
```

**Into**

```
<div id="divAddCustomerInfo" runat="server" style="visibility:hidden;margin-left:300px; margin-top:50px;">
```

Comment: "divAddCustomerInfo" is visible even before click on image

Answer (score 0):

Update the following portion as

```
<div id="divAddition" onclick="divAddition_click()" style="height:100px; float:left; width:300px; " >
            <img id="imgAdd" onclick="imgAdd_click()" src="001446-3d-transparent-glass-icon-media-a-media35-add.png" style="height:70px; width:70px; display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" />
            <label id="lblAdd" onclick="lblADD_click()" style="color: #a6a6a6; margin-left:100px;">Add Customer</label>
        </div>
```

Comment: thankyou. click on image does alert a message. but div "divAddCustomerInfo" is visible even before click on image. any suggestion?

Answer (score -2):

It is working version of your code (see below):
Your mistakes:

- the absence of brackets in `onclick`
- the absence `visibility: hidden;` in `div id="divAddCustomerInfo"`

---

```
<div id="divCustomerBody" style="margin-left:300px; margin-top:50px;">
    <h1>Customer</h1>
    <hr style="color:gray; width:900px; margin-left: 0px;" />
    <br />
    <div id="divOperationSymbol" style="height:100px; width:900px; ">

        <div id="divAddition" onclick="divAddition_click()" style="height:100px; float:left; width:300px; " >
            <img id="imgAdd" onclick="imgAdd_click()" src="http://www.ipac.caltech.edu/2mass/gallery/antennae.jpg" style="height:70px; width:70px; display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" />
            <label id="lblAdd" onclick="lblADD_click()" style="color: #a6a6a6; margin-left:100px;">Add Customer</label>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div id="divAddCustomerInfo" runat="server"   style="margin-left:300px; margin-top:50px; visibility:hidden">
    Text
</div>
```

---

```
function imgAdd_click() {
    document.getElementById("divAddCustomerInfo").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear how simply cutting and pasting the OPs question back as an answer and saying "It works as you want" helps anyone?

Comment: @Liam Don't understand, move on.